# Netvox Zigbee end device not joining my zigbee coordinator

Tags: zigbee

I am implementing Zigbee Gateway with **TIcc2530 SOC** using ZStack for home automation and want to integrate various Netvox devices like Z211 IR Transmitter etc with our gateway.

But I am facing problem in joining of these devices to my zigbee network created by my gateway.

I have enabled the Association Permit join in my gateway, but these devices are unable to add to the zigbee network.

**With packet sniffer we check that:**
Devices keeps searching network with Beacons, and observed that it sends association request for which we send association permit response from gateway then Transport Key command (default HA security key) is send from gateway but it keep repeating process of sending again association request  and unable to join.

Does anyone  has tried with these netvox end devices to join  cc2530 coordinator and can provide solution or dependencies netvox device requires .

Thankful if help can be provided for the same.

Comment: Can you get a capture from the Netvox device joining to another gateway, and compare your beacon responses to the gateway that works?  There's likely a field in your beacon response that results in the Netvox ignoring it.  I recall seeing that happen when a device listed the wrong "stack profile" in its beacon responses.

Answer (score 0):

If the end device is getting confused by your network key, it's possible that it doesn't support encryption. This can be tested by disabling security on your coordinator, after which all your messages will be sent in the clear. Alternatively, there could be an out-of-band commissioning scheme, or a hardcoded manufacturer key. I like tomlogic's idea to get a capture of the device joining a known good coordinator to find out what it does differently.

It's also possible that the Netvox device is using 802.15.4 for communication but does not actually implement ZigBee networking. In that case, it will still use the same beacons and association packets, but your ZigBee network key will be totally unrecognized. The Netvox website shows that they claim to be an "802.15.04 specialist", so there's a chance that some of their devices aren't using (or don't need) the ZigBee protocol.

Even if it does implement ZigBee, many of the variations within ZigBee can prevent two devices from communicating. For example, the Netvox may have no application profile support for HA, so your HA security keys won't be recognized. Tom's also right that the "stack profile" can prevent devices from joining if they are different (for example, one uses ZigBee PRO and the other does not). Some manufacturers will intentionally advertise non-standard profiles in their beacons to prevent use of their devices in other ZigBee networks. This allows developers on a budget to make hardcoded assumptions about other devices in the network. Based on your description, the Netvox didn't know how to handle the unexpected condition, and got stuck in an endless loop. Again, the capture can help you verify this.

Comment: I checked with both secured and Unsecured options, but behaviour remained same. I checked in beacon packets send by end devices   and they follow Zigbee protocol , also through checking value of stack_profile(through which we can know is it zigbeePro or zigbee2007 ), for both coordinator and netvox device it was same ZIgbeePro. I had one motion sensor of other company (Climax Technology) and try to make it join with coordinator, it joined properly and send device announce after association. But same coordinator I am using with Netvox device but its  not joining properly.

Answer (score -1):

Some end devices require that you bind to one of its clusters, or have it assigned to a group, for it to have some assurance that it has not accidentally joined the wrong network.  Hope this helps.